# SSIS require expression variable to accept object variable as comma separated value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, for-loop, ssis

**Problem**

We have an existing SSIS package that takes 4-5 hours to run. This package uses an ODBC connection to look at a MYSQL database and queries a transactional table using a where clause that looks at a non-indexed date field. The table has over 95 million rows and grows by several thousand a day. We cannot create a new index on the table to try and improve the query speed.

**edit** - the MYSQL table has an index on an ID value which can be linked to data that exists within a MSSQL database table

The speed of the package has got worse and worse as the number of transactions in the MYSQL table increases. When it was originally designed querying on the none-indexed date field worked fine but now it doesn't.

**Potential Solution**

The table has a foreign key (customer id) that is saved into an SQL server data warehouse as part of another package run for customer information (where it is the primary key). This cohort is around 35,000 individuals in a month.

I can query the customer information and return the cohort of customers that we then want to query the transactional table for. We would then use some lookup transformations to pull the rest of the data that we want.

We are ultimately wanting to query the 95 million records in the original table in MYSQL to only return those who are in the customer table in MSSQL.

**Current none-complete solution**

In SSIS I have created an SQL task that identifies the cohort of individuals from the MSSQL DB (35,000 records). I can pass a single value via a string variable to a data flow task that then uses an expression for an ADO Net Source to push the data to a Recordset Destination (for testing purposes)

I am aware that I cannot use Object variables in an expression so need to either convert the object to a comma separate string or use another tool to complete the process.

I am thinking I can use a For Each Loop container to iterate through the MSSQL list and only return those value in the MYSQL list that match. I've spent a while looking at this and most examples of the For Each Loop container I've found detail how it can be used to create multiple export files in a network location, so it isn't really allowing me to self learn that element in the way I want to use it.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to match up an MYSQL and a MSSQL database without having to return the 95 million rows of data in the package and then having a step that only looks up those from the other source, as I cannot feasibly pull down the 95 million rows into the package and then undertake a lookup translation as it takes a long time to load the millions of records.

Comment: If you have no index on the table, then the data engine is *always* going to have to scan the entire table. It doesn't matter if you want to limit the rows you want back, a full scan will occur. From the data engines point of view, "Get all the rows, and then compare" and "Get details of the rows you need, and get those rows" will both end up with "Read the entire table, as you have no index to help you find the rows you need." Why are you against adding an index?

Comment: We have an index on the ID value which is what I can pull from the customer table in MSSQL and cross reference, we don't have an index on the date value.  We cannot add a index to the table for the date value

Comment: *"We cannot add a index to the table for the date value"* You didn't answer *why*.

Comment: We are not allowed to add an index to the date value of the MSSQL table

Comment: Then speak to someone who *is* allowed, as that seems to be your problem; a lack of good indexing.